# DropDownList SelectedItem Not Working (Razor ASP MVC5)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Model**

```
public class MyModel {
     public string ItemXYZ { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
  var x = db.XYZs.Find(id);
  ViewBag.Item_XYZ = new SelectList(new[] { "X", "Y", "Z"}, x.CurrentXYZ);
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("XYZ123", @ViewBag.Item_XYZ as SelectList, new { @class = "special-class" })
```

**Problem**

If I change my DropDownList to mach the name of the get set in my model, the selected value does not work.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ItemXYZ" ....)
```

If it matches the name of my `ViewBag` item, the `SelectedItem` doesn't work.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Item_XYZ" ....)
```

But, if I append `123` (for example), `SelectedItem` works just fine.

**UPDATE**

[**This is the same issue**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19748699/3325793) I am having, but I don't understand why or how to handle the return in my controller?

Comment: Also, how do I access the posted value for `XYZ123`, since its not tied to my model in my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Controller use the code as::

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
  var x = db.XYZs.ToList();
  ViewBag.TestDropdown = new SelectList(x, "ValueField", "TextField", "DefaultSelected");
}
```

and in Client side to show Dropdown use this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("TestDropdown")
```

thats it.
May be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Receive a parameter named XYZ123 in respective action.
Also include XYZ123 in Bind attribute of action.